# Implement "Hello World" using RabbitMq

Tags: rabbitmq

Hie..I am a beginner to RabbitMQ. The IDE used is eclipse and language is Java. I want to know if it is possible to run a hello world example without setting up local server??

Comment: You know that setting up a local server is 10 seconds of work? At least on linux....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use https://www.cloudamqp.com/

There is free plan that is perfect to try:

https://www.cloudamqp.com/plans.html

Little Lemur For development

```
Max 1M messages per month
Max 20 concurrent connections
Max 100 queues
Max 10 000 queued messages
```

Comment: But I am not able to see my details after signing up